# Delphi XE2 TPointerList usage

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tlist

I have a following problem trying to compile some components in XE2. These components were not prepared for XE2, but I'm trying to compile them anyway.

Within a component it is declared like

```
FList : TList;
```

when used it is for example like

```
SomeVariable := Integer(FList.List^[i]);
```

It produces "Pointer type required" compile error.

I can be corrected it like this

```
SomeVariable := Integer(FList.List[i]);
```

but god knows how much time would I need to fix all occurencies of error.

Is there some compiler directive, or setting that can handle this. I've tried {$X} and {$T} without effect.

In XE2 Delphi TPointerList (TList.List property) is declared as dynamic array

```
type TPointerList = array of Pointer;
```

If anyone can help?

Comment: No, you have to change the 3rd party code. Or get an update from the code vendor.

Comment: Also, your "correction" is incorrect. You mean: `Integer(FList.List[i])`

Comment: I think that you should never call an "Array of X" a "List", especially in a type declaration.  Such confusion is only going to annoy people.  TList-types have Add(x) methods, for instance, whereas Arrays are not object-types at all, and you have to SetLength, instead.  Thus, "TSomethingList" is  not a good name for an alias of "Array of Pointer".

Comment: @warren you should address that to the author of the code, emba

Comment: @david You are right about my "correction", I forgot to edit it, now its corrected here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Integer(FList[i]) would also work.

b) There is no such setting.

c) Maybe you can Search&Replace .List^[ -> [ ?

Comment: I will use Search & Replace like that. I just found out TList.List was changed in XE2, it was PPointerList prior to XE2 ...